# How can a float value be trimmed to the first three digits?

Tags: java, floating-point

its my first question here and maybe i'm just blind or extremely stupid, but i haven't found a matching answer to my problem in the past three days. Currently i'm coding an Idlegame (just to learn more about OOP and such stuff) and obviously there will be some numbers that are too big for int or long (sth like "1500000000000" (1.5E12)). So i decided to go along with floats for two reasons:

1. Every other type that can store way more than int or long (like BigInteger or BigDecimal) wouldn't solve my problem of shortening my shown numbers in the ui.
2. I like the numberformatting of float with the exponent shown at the end.

Because of some issues with the length of the outcoming number (1.50000003E12 (i think the ...03 at the end of the number comes from the Float.toString() which i use to set it onto a javafx label)) i thought about formatting them in an uniform way (in my opinion it should look like 1.23E45) so i googled a lot, read a lot, tried a lot, but still got no working solution. on SO i read multiple ways to format floats with "String.format()" and "DecimalFormat", but the outcome wasn't as expected. the float value is written completely what in fact is the opposite of that, what i wanna achieve.

So my wish would be a working solution, or a hint that would help me further to achieve my goal to only show the first three digits of a float and add the exponent.

If anything is missing that would help to find the best solution for my problem feel free to ask for it.

Comment: What did you try with `String.format()`? What were the results, and what did you find objectional about those results?

Comment: I tried to String.format("%.2f", vlaue); the float, in hope to get a result like 1.23E45, but got something like 1234567.00. So the result was a little bit different from what im looking for. like this: http://prntscr.com/k390o0

Comment: Probably not ideal, but: `String st = String.valueOf(number);` and `System.out.println(st.substring(0, 3) + st.substring(st.length()-3));`.

Comment: Try an "e" conversion like `%8.2e`;  that will give exponent notation with two decimal places, overall width of 8.

Comment: @KevinAnderson nice step in the right direction but not completely what im looking for, as the result looks like "1.50e+12" for "1500000000000F" what definitly is correct, but the solution provided by notyou does the trick as my wish for the outcome should look like. would appreciate if you both would give your solutions as answer so i can mark a solution and this topic as solved c: